Intel MIPI Camera stopped working on DELL Precision 5480 after update
My laptop was working very well with kernel 6.5.0-1025-oem on 22.04 LTS, including the integrated webcam. After an update, the webcam is not working anymore.
The camera is still detected as follows:
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

How to debug ?
Thanks in advance.
